# css background image on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, background-image

Is there a reason this background image wouldn't work on mobile? It works fine on desktop and shows up on my browser mobile simulator but I have a QA guy over seas saying it's not working on his mobile emulator.

```
class_name  {
background: url("../case_studies/mini/results_bg.jpg?") center top fixed no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```

Comment: You've missed the `.` before the class name and the closing curly brace, though I assume that's just in this post rather than your original code as you said it was working for you. You could also add `background-size: cover;`, the non-browser specific version of that command. Other than that, it depends what browser he is using.

Comment: Also look into background-attachment: fixed, it's always given me issues on mobile browsers.

Comment: @Ninjakannon thanks guys. It was the "fixed" that was making it disappear on mobile so I just made a media query that took off the fixed position when it got to tablet/mobile size